# How to make a loop that loops 25 times, waits 5 minutes and then starts the next batch of 25? java

Tags: loops, if-statement, wait

I know that I'll have a for `loop` that looks something like this. But other than that I have no idea for it to then start back up again :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    // my code here
}
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pause the thread that your loop is running in, use;

```
Thread.sleep (num_milliseconds);
```

If you want it to run every 5 minutes just use

```
while (true){
    for (int i = 0; i<25; i++){
        // your code
        Thread.sleep(300000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Right I have no problem pausing it. My issue is how do i pause it only after each set of 25 and then start up again where it left off.

Comment: Well if you add thread.sleep as the last line within your loop, and include the loop inside its own loop, it should pause it "only after each set of 25".. Edited the answer :)